# ESP8266 Arduino запись звука и передача на ftp

Tags: arduino, wifi, микроконтроллеры, звукозапись

есть задача настроить запись звука и передача его на ftp
Возникла мысль собрать простую схемку из esp8266 и микрофона, будет ли такое работать? И есть ли у кого идеи как такое реализовать?
На платной основе

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://www.hackster.io/mvtdesign/wifi-microphone-with-arduino-and-esp8266-updated-69934d